Vue 3 suspense with loading skeleton not working
I am writing a Vue 3 app and I'm using suspense. It's not working like I expect, so I found a codepen that does what I want: https://codepen.io/ajithranka/pen/RwjBJbr
So, I exported it and ran it locally just fine. Next, I created a standard Vue application:
 npm create vite@latest loading-app -- --template vue

Then, I created Vue components and views and when I run the new app, I get:

I know what the error means, but I don't know why it's happening. Even when I check if the data variable is not null, the skeletons do not appear.
I created a public github (https://github.com/troycomp/loading-app) project with what I created from the codepen. Will someone show me why the skeletons are not appearing like the example?
Thanks

The reason this isn't working is because you are essentially doing this: null.title. That is what the error is trying to tell you. At the time you try to access the title property the object is null because the data needs to be fetched. Try using the optional chaining operator ?.title

It defeats the purpose of using <Suspended> though, which is meant to show skeleton component in this case while data is being fetched and still null, the problem is in how the data is being fetched.  I will post answer

I agree. I thought the component where the data is being displayed would not be hit until data is actually fetched. I'll await your answer. Thanks

According to Vue documentation:

There are two types of async dependencies that <Suspense> can wait on:

Components with an async setup() hook. This includes components using <script setup> with top-level await expressions.

Async Components.



In your github code, in SuspendableComponent.vue, you are fetching within your onMounted hook
onMounted(async () => {
  data.value = await fetchData({
    dataIndex: props.dataIndex,
    delay: props.delay,
    throwError: props.throwError,
  });
});

This is not considered top-level code, therefore <Suspense> does not wait on it. To be top-level the fetch should be moved outside of onMounted.
data.value = await fetchData({
  dataIndex: props.dataIndex,
  delay: props.delay,
  throwError: props.throwError,
});


OMG, that actually worked. The skeletons are showing as expected. Thanks for researching this. I didn't know about top-level code. I do now :)
